# Add Mapbox to Android View in Xamarin Forms Custom Renderer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mapbox

I cannot figure out how to get a Mapbox map going in a custom view renderer on Android using Xamarin.Forms. It's driving me bonkers.

In my PCL, I have a map view.

```
public class MapView: View
{
    public MapView() { }
}
```

For iOS, the "getting started" help was close enough to get it working on iOS, like so:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(Shared.Mobile.MapView), typeof(MapViewRenderer))]
namespace Clients.iOS
{
    public class MapViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Shared.Mobile.MapView, UIView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Shared.Mobile.MapView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var uiView = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 500, 700));
            SetNativeControl(uiView);

            var mapView = new MapView(Control.Bounds);
            mapView.SetCenterCoordinate(new CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D(40.81, -96.68), false);
            mapView.SetZoomLevel(11, false);

            mapView.AddAnnotation(new PointAnnotation
                {
                    Coordinate = new CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D(40.81, -96.68), 
                    Title = "Lincoln, NE",
                    Subtitle = "What-what"
                });

            uiView.AddSubview(mapView);
        }
    }
}
```

On the Android side, not so much. (https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/mapboxsdk). They're putting in XML and an Activity of sorts, but my knowledge in mobile doesn't extend far from Xamarin.Forms at the moment, so I can't seem to bridge the gap between the two. My Android renderer looks like this:

```
public class MapViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Shared.Mobile.MapView, Android.Views.View>
{     
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Shared.Mobile.MapView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = new Android.Views.View(Context);
        SetNativeControl(view);  // NullReferenceException will be thrown if the native control is not set

        if (Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var mapView = new MapView(Forms.Context, "thisismyaccesscode");
        mapView.CenterCoordinate = new LatLng(41.885, -87.679);
        mapView.ZoomLevel = 11;
        mapView.SetMinimumHeight(250);
        mapView.SetMinimumWidth(250);
        mapView.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(40.81, -96.68)).SetTitle("Lincoln, NE"));

        view.AddSubview(mapView) // I wish this method existed
    }
}
```

My final call to `AddSubview(mapView)` is not in fact a method of the `View` class as it is the `UIView` class on iOS. Here's where I'm stuck. I cannot figure out how to display the `MapView`. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to create the XML as suggested in your link? That's how views are normally completed on Android. As mentioned in the [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_deepdive/#OnCreate), you need to call ``SetContentView()`` in `ÒnCreate()``

Comment: I did try that but it wasn't working out, and rather than dig too much into how it's normally done on Android, I tried to go the xamarin.forms route (the only way I am somewhat familiar). I will look into the xml approach and see if I have better luck.

Comment: Could you possibly add what you've tried to your post that didn't work out? Additionally, Xamarin describes in [this post how you can customize your map on each platform]. Maybe that will lead you in a direction. 

Did you also make sure to set your ``ExportRenderer`` in your platform specific code?

Comment: @Andy Have you managed to make any more progress?  If your still stuck, why not send over your solution and I will take a quick look?  My contact details are on my profile.

Comment: @Pete no I haven't. I took your advice and it seemed to get closer, but the app crashes immediately on some devices and research points to this being a current mapbox bug. What's more, the mapbox sdk will not run with the most current xamarin.forms version. At this point I don't have time to screw around with mapbox anymore so may just go with native maps.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already mentioned you can't call `AddSubview` as it is an `iOS` method.

On `Android` its the equivalent of `AddView`.

However - You are attempting to do this type of operation on a `Android` `View` object and not on a `ViewGroup` object, so its not possible.

First instead of doing:-

```
var view = new Android.Views.View(Context);
```

try instantiating the MapView directly such like:-

```
var view = new MapView(Context, "thisismyaccesscode");
```

Your `SetNativeControl` call on the view is fine.

I haven't tried the Mapbox component, so I'm unclear on the exact parameter types it is expecting in the code above.

Should that not work, however, then do something like the following:-

```
var view = new Android.Widget.FrameLayout(Context);

var mapView = new MapView(Forms.Context, "thisismyaccesscode");
mapView.CenterCoordinate = new LatLng(41.885, -87.679);
mapView.ZoomLevel = 11;
mapView.SetMinimumHeight(250);
mapView.SetMinimumWidth(250);
mapView.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(40.81, -96.68)).SetTitle("Lincoln, NE"));

view.AddView(mapView);

SetNativeControl(view);
```

You will have to change your first line to the following also:-

```
public class MapViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Shared.Mobile.MapView, Android.Widget.FrameLayout>
```